# Jenkins get status of last build with a specific parameter

Tags: bash, jenkins, curl, devops, jenkins-cli

I have a Jenkins freestyle job (yeah I know..) that sometimes needs to wait for another job with the same parameter to finish if it's running (or not run at all if it failed).

Using `curl` and the Jenkins API, is it possible to query a certain job and get the status of the last build where `certainParam=certainValue`?

(The reason I'm asking how to do that with curl is because it doesn't seem to be possible to do in freestyle job and the job can't be migrated to pipeilnes yet.. It seems like curl would be the east way..)

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0):

So far I know there's no direct way to achieve it.

I wrote recursive script that search by the values on each build from the very last until match the information.

It prints every build url and the result of the query.

**Dependencies**

- jq - install "jq.x86_64", Command-line JSON processor

**Script**

```
#!/bin/bash

user="admin"
pwd="11966e4dd8c33a730abf88e98fb952ebc3"

builds=$(curl -s --user $user:$pwd localhost:8080/job/test/api/json)

urls=$(echo $builds | jq '.builds[] | .url')

while read -r url
do
  url=$(echo $url | sed -nr 's/"([^|]*)"/\1/p')

  # get the build log
  build=$(curl -s --user $user:$pwd "${url}api/json")

  # transform the log in a simple structure
  build=$(echo $build | jq '.result as $result | .actions[].parameters[]? | select(.name == "certainParam") | {(.name): .value, "result": $result}')

  # check if the parameter value and the build result are the expected
  result=$(echo $build | jq 'if .certainParam == "certainValue" and .result == "SUCCESS" then true else false end')

  # print the result of each build
  echo "url=${url}api/json;result=$result"

  if [[ $result == true ]]
  then
    break
  fi
done <<< $urls
```

**Result**

> sh jenkins.sh 
> url=http://localhost:8080/job/test/12/api/json;result=false
> url=http://localhost:8080/job/test/11/api/json;result=true